# Argo delete pods in Crash loopback off

Tags: argo

I have local argo set up where i started argo server and controller and it went into crash loopback state.

Following is state of pods:

```
[spark_argo_test]$ kubectl -n argo-events get pods 
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE
argo-server-78b4844f66-fkkx9                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   242 (3m21s ago)   20h
eventbus-controller-f8ffd4d59-px59c                         1/1     Running            0                 24h
eventbus-default-stan-0                                     2/2     Running            0                 24h
eventbus-default-stan-1                                     2/2     Running            0                 24h
eventbus-default-stan-2                                     2/2     Running            0                 24h
events-webhook-565b76759-vfnz5                              1/1     Running            0                 24h
eventsource-controller-6547c66494-957fc                     1/1     Running            0                 24h
sensor-controller-7ffb6c5486-vl94s                          1/1     Running            0                 24h
sqs-es-testqueue-descap-eventsource-lq5m8-f87f7c76b-m2kdc   1/1     Running            137 (5m25s ago)   16h
workflow-controller-756c8c87ff-88tc8                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   242 (4m15s ago)   20h
```

Here if we see the argo server and argo controller is in Crash loopBack state.
Even if i want to see logs there is nothing which i can see in

```
[srivastu@a-uexsrqhp5gj1 spark_argo_test]$ kubectl -n argo-events logs argo-server-78b4844f66-fkkx9 -c main
error: container main is not valid for pod argo-server-78b4844f66-fkkx9
```

When deleting the pod there is no delete happening in by following command.

```
[srivastu@a-uexsrqhp5gj1 spark_argo_test]$ kubectl -n argo-events delete pod argo-server-78b4844f66-fkkx9
pod "argo-server-78b4844f66-fkkx9" deleted
```

The pod gets deleted but again it restarts after some time and it seems local minkube cluster starts the argo server again.

Can anyone please help around this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked by following commands

```
[ spark_argo_test]$ kubectl get deployments -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
argo-events            eventbus-controller                         1/1     1            1           24h
argo-events            events-webhook                              1/1     1            1           24h
argo-events            eventsource-controller                      1/1     1            1           24h
argo-events            sensor-controller                           1/1     1            1           24h
argo-events            sqs-es-testqueue-descap-eventsource-lq5m8   1/1     1            1           24h
argo-events            workflow-controller                         0/1     1            0           20h
argo                   workflow-controller                         1/1     1            1           41d
kube-system            coredns                                     1/1     1            1           41d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper                   1/1     1            1           41d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                        1/1     1            1           41d
[@a-uexsrqhp5gj1 spark_argo_test]$ kubectl delete -n argo-events deployment workflow-controller
deployment.apps "workflow-controller" deleted
[@a-uexsrqhp5gj1 spark_argo_test]$ kubectl delete -n argo deployment workflow-controller
deployment.apps "workflow-controller" deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked by following commands:

> liseht@Azure:~$ kubectl -n qa delete pod yape-mocks-qa-desa-78fcfd5dk9-wq75z

> pod "yape-mocks-qa-desa-78fcfd5dk9-wq75z" deleted

> liseht@Azure:~$ kubectl -n qa get pods

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    yape-mocks-qa-cert-6cbdb4f9f8-d9vwb    1/1     Running   0          7d13h
    yape-mocks-qa-desa-58fcfd5ff9-fq7rw    1/1     Running   0          40s
    yape-mocks-qa-desa1-5984b548dc-jcg89   1/1     Running   0          11d
    yape-mocks-qa-stress-68bb54b4b-cwh5t   1/1     Running   0          3h51m
    yape-mocks-qa-stress-68bb38b4b-jmngv   1/1     Running   0          4d11h
```